# expand data frames inside data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
   language  subID sessionID                  rdm
      (chr) (fctr)    (fctr)                (chr)
1     Dutch  13602     13257 <data.frame [676,3]>
2     Dutch  13602    125354 <data.frame [676,3]>
3     Dutch  17790     19308 <data.frame [676,3]>
4     Dutch  37016     38221 <data.frame [676,3]>
5     Dutch  46830     47890 <data.frame [676,3]>
```

I would like to transform this data frame into a 676*n by 6 data frame - in other words, take the rdm column of data frames and expand it in to the larger data frame.

I would *like* to be able to do something like:

```
bind_rows(data_frame$rdm,.id=c(data_frame$sessionID,data_frame$subID,data_frame$language))
```

But, obviously, the ".id" attribute doesn't work that way. How can I get the data frame I'm after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `unnest` from `library(tidyr)`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(df1, rdm)
#  Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

#  language sessionID    V1    V2
#     (chr)     (dbl) (int) (int)
#1    Dutch     13257     1     2
#2    Dutch     13257     2     3
#3    Dutch     13257     3     4
#4    Dutch    125354     4     5
#5    Dutch    125354     5     6
#6    Dutch    125354     6     7
```

#### data

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data_frame(language=c('Dutch', 'Dutch'), sessionID=c(13257, 125354),
  rdm= list(data.frame(V1=1:3, V2=2:4), data.frame(V1=4:6, V2=5:7)))
```

Comment: didn't know about this one. superb.

Comment: awesome, thanks! wow, so fast I can't even accept the answer for another 3 minutes

Comment: I thought the OP wanted rownames(df) <- paste0(data_frame$sessionID,data_frame$subID,data_frame$language) where df is his large df and R recycles the 5 lines to fit all the way down.